# How to load my rootview everytime when the tab is selected?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an Iphone application in which i have 3 tabitems with a tabbarcontroller.Inside the tabbarcontroller each viewcontroller is a navigation controller.when selecting the second tab i have a view controller.when selecting a button on that i am pushing another view controller to the self.navigation controller.and in that viewcontroller i am pushing and go like that.But the problem is when i am selecting the tabitem again that pushedviewcotrooller is shown there.but i need that rootview there again when i am selecting the tab,i tried like this in my code but not worked,`

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabbBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(tabBarController.selectedIndex==0)
    {
        //[viewController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinboard_hvr.png"]];
    }
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",viewController);
       //[viewController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinboard_hvr.png"]];
       // NSArray *array = [viewController.navigationController viewControllers];
        NSLog(@"%@",array);

       // [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];


        [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        //[appdelegate.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==2)
    {

        //[viewController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinboard_hvr.png"]];  

    }
}
```

`i have tried both with poping to root and also by taking the array of view controllers,but not worked.Can anybody help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me too had a similar problem which I solved by the following code.

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabbBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==1)
    {
         NSArray *mycontrollers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
         [[mycontrollers objectAtIndex:1] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
         mycontrollers = nil;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The argument you have received in delegate is itself a navigationController.
So, change statement like below,

```
else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==1)
    {
        [((UINavigationController *)viewController) popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        //[appdelegate.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
```